# Sending emails with Bamboo in a mix task

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to send an email from a mix task with [Bamboo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo). Here is the code of the task:

```erlang
defmodule Mix.Tasks.SendEmails.Reminder do
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto
  import Ecto.Query

  def run(_args) do
    Foobar.welcome_email |> MyApp.Mailer.deliver_now
  end
end

defmodule Foobar do
  import Bamboo.Email

  def welcome_email do
    new_email
    |> to("foo@example.com")
    |> from("me@example.com")
    |> subject("Welcome!!!")
    |> html_body("<strong>Welcome</strong>")
    |> text_body("welcome")
  end
end
```

When I run this mix task I get the following log output:

```
21:20:26.829 [debug] Sending email with Bamboo.LocalAdapter:

%Bamboo.Email{assigns: %{}, bcc: [], cc: [], from: {nil, 
"me@example.com"}, headers: %{}, html_body: "<strong>Welcome</strong>",
private: %{}, subject: "Welcome!!!", text_body: "welcome", to: 
[nil: "foo@example.com"]}

** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(Bamboo.SentEmail, {:update, 
    #Function<2.18788267/1 in Bamboo.SentEmail.push/1>}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no 
    process currently associated with the given name, possibly 
    because its application isn't started
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:729: GenServer.call/3
    lib/bamboo/sent_email.ex:109: Bamboo.SentEmail.push/1
    lib/bamboo/mailer.ex:121: Bamboo.Mailer.deliver_now/3
    lib/mix/tasks/send_emails.reminder.ex:30: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Tasks.SendEmails.Reminder.run/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    lib/mix/tasks/send_emails.reminder.ex:20: Mix.Tasks.SendEmails.Reminder.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:294: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:370: Code.require_file/2
```

How can I fix this? Bamboo works fine in the Phoenix app. I just can't get it running within a mix task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurs because `bamboo` wasn't started.

### Start a single application

Use [Application.ensure_all_started/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#ensure_all_started/2) to start a specific application, in your case:

```
Application.ensure_all_started(:bamboo)
```

### Start all applications

In some cases you may want to start all applications:
[Mix.Tasks.App.Start](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.App.Start.html) will start all applications defined in your `mix.exs` config:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.SendEmails.Reminder do
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto
  import Ecto.Query

  def run(_args) do
    Mix.Tasks.App.Start.run([]) # This will start all apps
    Foobar.welcome_email |> MyApp.Mailer.deliver_now
  end
end
```

Comment: `Application.ensure_all_started(:bamboo)` in this case is better solution, since you won't start the whole app, just the required dependency.

Comment: @PatNowak True, edited the answer, `Application.ensure_all_started` is now the primary solution.

Comment: WARNING: You should not `import Mix.Ecto` as Mix.Ecto is considered a private API https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1586#issuecomment-233301683